# Fatal error: Call to a member function getType() on a non-object

Tags: php

Just today when i opened my site i found this fatal error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getType() on a non-object in /nfs/c08/h03/mnt/152783/domains/jobs.mediajobs.com/html/system/lib/orm/ObjectProperty.php on line 427

And when i searched for that line i found this code :

```
function getType() { return $this->type->getType(); }
```

I don't have any idea of what might have happened.

The whole code i pasted here ..

http://pastie.org/private/lb3sfkkytzofxer2gtynvq

Please Help!

Comment: put your error in google, it would've gotten you an instant answer

Answer (score 0):

Check what `$this->type` is. Your code expects it to be an object, and it apparently isn't.

Comment: My php knowledge is very limited, but I'm trying to know what this is for.

Comment: We can't possibly tell you that just from this one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->type` is currently not an object. Check you have initialize (or set) it and if you don't override the object with a int, string or whatever by accident.

Comment: This code belongs to a software named Job Board Software, and the error is in the core files of the software which i hadn't touched.

Comment: This error appeared just today suddenly.Also, if i remove the line which causes the error, i get another error for another gettype() function.

Comment: You can see the code here on this link : [http://pastie.org/private/lb3sfkkytzofxer2gtynvq]